# linq manipulate list of custom object

Tags: c#, linq

Here is my code so far, returning some data from SQL server:

```
try
{
    connection.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = "select * from dbo.contact";
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    List<person> persons = new List<person>();
    person person;
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        person = new person();
        persons.Add(person);
    }
    persons.Count();
}
catch {

}
```

what I want to next is to extract specific records from the list by using LINQ. For example, a linq that returns all persons that have a DName='D'.

Here is the code of the object:

```
public class person
{
    public string idvalue { get; set; }

    public string DName { get; set; }

    public string FName { get; set; }

}
```

Any help is welcome!

Comment: And what´s the problem?

Comment: Do you use anyhow `SqlDataReader` ? Or for each record read from db, you're creating a new person (seems to be empty) and adding to collection ? `while (dr.Read())
    {
        person = new person();
        persons.Add(person);
    }`

Comment: You are mixing 2 different concepts here. Using a Data Reader and also retrieving data using Linq to sql or EF. You cant do both, pick one or the other. I recommend you do a tutorial or do some reading on these concepts before you proceed any further.

Comment: Filtering should be done in the query string as much as possible to limit the amount of data returned by the database. This is very important if the database is big and remote.

Comment: By the way, the code can be improved a lot...

    - Follow .NET nomenclature.
    - Avoid hiding exceptions.
    - Declare variable at their first use.
    - Initialize added persons from database records.
    - Properly manage opening and closing of connections.
    - Remove useless call to `Count()`.
    - ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I'd do it:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<person> FilteredPeople = GetPeople("D");
    }
    static List<person> GetPeople(string condition)
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select * from dbo.contact WHERE DName LIKE @mycondition", connection))
            {
                 cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("mycondition", condition));
                 SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                 List<person> persons = new List<person>();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                     person p = new person();
                     p.idValue = dr["Id"].ToString();
                     p.DName = dr["DName"].ToString();
                     p.FName = dr["FName"].ToString();
                     persons.Add(p);
                 }
                 return persons;
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }
```

As others pointed out, it is wise to minimize the load on the database, therefore it's better to insert the condition on the SQLCommand so as to draw only the necessary records.

EDIT: woops forgot to close the connection, I suggest inserting another "using" clause for the sqlConnection, so that it disposes itself once it reaches the end (using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{})

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the following is what you are looking for. It will return an IEnumerable with one result

```
public class Person
{
    public string idvalue { get; set; }
    public string DName { get; set; }
    public string FName { get; set; }
}

List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();
persons.Add(new Person { DName = "A" });
persons.Add(new Person { DName = "B" });
persons.Add(new Person { DName = "C" });
persons.Add(new Person { DName = "D" });
var result = persons.Where(p => p.DName == "D");
result.Dump();
```